# How to get a specific value from a json array out of a list of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, file-get-contents

everyone, I was just trying to find out a way to get the value of a link from a JSON array , after I have searched the array with help of Id. I am using PHP's `file_get_contents` and the webpage from which information is to be taken looks like

```
[{
    "id":"2972",
    "name": "AbC",
    "link":"any link",
    "epg": "any link",
    "dur": "disabled",
    "language": "y",
    "category": "TOP 100",
    "logo": "any url here"
},
{
    "id": "1858",
    "name": "Efg",
    "link": "url",
    "epg": "url",
    "dvr": "disabled",
    "language": "E",
    "category": "TOP 100",
    "logo": "url"
}]
```

From here suppose I have been given an Id `1858` so I have to find a link from the array of Id having `1858`

I am a beginner in PHP and was just fidgeting around with a piece of code and tried to get its solution and a big Thanks **To You For Your Answer and valuable Time.**

Comment: The posted data isn't valid json. That's just two objects outputted after each other. Are they actually in an array: `[ ... ]` and with comma in between `[{...}, {...}]`?

Comment: Sir I have a similar array on the webpage but some commas are missing If you want shall I reedit and add those commas to make it look like an array or a json

Comment: Please post the data as is". It's hard for us to help if we can't trust the data we see. It's ok to remove irrelevant data (or remove some objects if there are many), but make sure what you post is still valid. You should also post the code you've tried, the expected result and what currently happens. We're glad to help you sort out issues with your existing code, but we're not here to write it for you.

Comment: If possible can you please visit http://access.richtv1.com/ch.php?usercode=5691007667&mac=B89BCD008419&customer=redline&check=3869096991 with user agent REDLINECLIENT G90 V10.36 , as the data is not being copied exactly .

Comment: Thanks for replying too

Comment: I have wrote the code but that goes beyond my ability to recopy it I just wanted the name or elements or codes that will be used , rest I will adjust it in my old code . Hope you understand me

Comment: I'm sorry, but all code/data must be included into the question itself. This is meant to be a big FAQ for programming issues. That means that it all needs to be searchable so others can see old questions. If you ask us to go off-site to get some info, then future visitors won't be able to benefit since it's not sure that links still works.

Comment: Please provide a proper `link` example. You may face `CORS` issue getting the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_column, to map pairs of json keys/values:

```
<?php
$json ='
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "link": "http:\/\/example.com\/3"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "link": "http:\/\/example.com\/5"
    }
]';

$data = json_decode($json, true);

if($data !== null) {
    echo array_column($data, 'link', 'id')[5] ?? null;
}
```

Output:

```
http://example.com/5
```

To understand this we can see the result of array_column.

```
var_export(array_column($data, 'link', 'id'));
```

Output:

```
array (
  3 => 'http://example.com/3',
  5 => 'http://example.com/5',
)
```

So with the above code, we are checking for and outputting the associated index of 5 (the original id).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `file_get_contents('php://input');`  then you should try this to access json data

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); //get json data in variable
$array = json_decode($json);  //parse json data in php array

// assecc the array with use of foreach loop
foreach($array as $obj){
//access the json element here like $id = $obj->id; $url = $obj->link;
//if you want to check the id value in array you can compare value with if condition
$id = $obj->id;
// find link for specific id
if($id =='1858'){
   $url = $obj->link;
   echo $url; // do something with link
   //you can use break; statement if you found your element and terminate the loop
}
}
```